# How do I modify my script to unhide all sheets subject to multiple exceptions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How would I modify this script to make multiple exceptions not just for one sheet? I am trying to unhide all sheets except for a few not just for one sheet.

```
function main(){
   activateAllSheetsExcept('Scripts');
}
function activateAllSheetsExcept(sheetName) {
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    if(sheets[i].getName()!=sheetName){
      sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
  }
}
```

Original thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38671585/21143626

Comment: Welcome to Web Application Stack Exchange. Why, if you found the code snipped in Stack Overflow, do you make the question here? Please show how you have tried adapting the script to your specific needs. Also, show this site's most relevant related questions and briefly explain why they don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), like this:

```
function test() {
  unhideAllSheetsExcept_(/^(Scripts|Config|Dropdowns)$/i);
}

function unhideAllSheetsExcept_(sheetRegex) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .forEach(sheet => {
      if (sheet.getName().match(sheetRegex)) return;
      sheet.showSheet();
    });
}
```